# Run more than one application in the same time

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, ssh, wine

I want to start my master server first:

```
cd /home/MasterServer
wine ForgeMasterServer.exe
```

Then I want to host my server:

```
cd /home/Forge
./forge.x86_64
```

Both of them should run after ssh client closes. I can do it by **tmux**.
But once I start any program I can't type any command? Or If I type it simply doesnt work. I searched the net but couldn't find any solution.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can background the process by appending a `&` at the end e.g.:

```
./forge.x86_64 &
```

You can do the same for other processes too.

To view the list of currently backgrounded jobs, check the output of `jobs` command. The jobs will be shown with a job ID on the left, which can be used to get the job in the foreground again by `fg %<Job_ID>` e.g.:

```
fg %1
```

Similarly to `kill` a job:

```
kill %1
```

---

On a different note, to keep the backgrounder process running after you detached from your current shell session, you can use `nohup` or `disown`:

```
./forge.x86_64 & disown
nohup ./forge.x86_64 & &>/dev/null
```